# GnuPG in Thunderbird w/ Enigmail on dual OS machine

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

I am running a computer with two OS, namely Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows. I'd like to write encypted Mails from both OS, which runs well (i.e., every program needed is installed).

The only problem I have is that the keyring is not the same. The obvious solution is to tell Unbuntu GnuPG to store the keyring in the folder of Windows GnuPG, since Unbuntu can see Windows folders but not the other way. The respective folder is, I think `%AppData%/gnupg`.

But how can I tell the Ubuntu GnuPG to store the keyring? So far, the ring is in `~/.gnupg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have shared GnuPG home directory, the Windows partition is always mounted, an easy, convenient and general solution would be to symlink the Windows GnuPG folder into your home directory. An advantage is you'd also share your trust database, a disadvantage that you might have trouble with permissions.

To do so, remove (after making a backup) the GnuPG folder in your home directory. Afterwards, run

```
 ln -s /path/to/your/windows/gnupg ~/.gnupg
```

As an alternative, simply export the private keys and import it again in Linux. Exporting is done using `gpg --export-secret-keys [keyid]`, importing as usual with `gpg --import`.

Comment: Do you also know how to sync the rules based on which mails are signed/encrypted?

Comment: This is implemented in Enigmail and stored in Thunderbird's home directory. You could use a shared Thunderbird profile.

Comment: For the interested reader: The symlinking can raise problems when you automount the Windows partition with too many rights. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/565230/gnupg-permissions-problems-on-dual-os-machine